# detectar 6 o más "/" en un texto aunque no estén juntos

Tags: regex

Buen día, quiero construir un regex que me permita saber cuando se han colocado 6 o más "/". es decir:

```
//texto//de//prueba ->true
texto//de//prueba   ->false
```

Tengo el regex que me da los 6 "/" cuando están juntos, no cuando están separados.

```
/\/{6,}/
```

¿cómo puedo lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es necesario hacer que coincida con todo lo que está en el medio, entre cada una de las barras, es decir, con cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean una barra `[^\/]*`.

Regex:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){6}
```

- El `(?:`...`){6}` es lo que te permite repetir 6 veces a todo lo que esté dentro de los paréntesis.